# Create PDF display Chinese as question marks using .NET

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, visual-studio-2017, pdfsharp

I am going to create an application which is used to generate a PDF file after clicking on a button. The application works well with English but not Chinese. I am using utf-8 to encode, so I cannot figure what causes the problem. Here is the main script:

```
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
            pdf.Info.Title = "My First PDF";
            PdfPage pdfPage = pdf.AddPage();
            XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);
            XFont font = new XFont("Microsoft Himalaya", 35, XFontStyle.Regular);
            graph.DrawString("香港", font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, pdfPage.Width.Point, 170), XStringFormats.Center);
            string pdfFilename = "firstpage.pdf";
            pdf.Save(pdfFilename);
            Process.Start(pdfFilename);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the app.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The encoding you use in your program does not matter, the font you create for the PDF is an ANSI font.

```
XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode,
                              PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

XFont font = new XFont("Times New Roman", 12, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
```

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Unicode-sample.ashx

The embedding option was removed IIRC, but you still have to set the encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Chinese characters change from question marks to squares after using the exact same code you provided. I changed Unicode to other font encoding method, but the characters disappeared. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Also make sure you are using a font that contains the glyphs you need. On my computer, "Microsoft Himalaya" contains Tibetan, but no CJK characters. Maybe try "Microsoft JhengHei". Use `charmap.exe` to check the needed glyphs are available.